# Need to insert variables to a Rest Call

Tags: java, resttemplate

I have this line of code which I use to do some post request to an api:

```
  restTemplate.postForLocation("http://uri.com", new HttpEntity<>("{\"messages\": [     {       \"to\": \"0213456\",       \"content\": \"text\"  } ] }", headers));
```

as The "**to**" parameter changes , i would like to insert a variable instead of the number **0213456** so i can use the same code line to address different cases.

Any idea how i can achieve that?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried [concatenating](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-concatenation-in-java) your variable into the string?

Comment: yes I did. Finally I found how to do it .             restTemplate.postForLocation("https://uri.com", new HttpEntity<>("{\"messages\": [     {        \\\"to\\\": \""+Number+"\",         \"content\": \"txt \"    }   ] }", headers)); Thank you for taking the time for responding.

Comment: If you've solved the issue, consider posting your solution as an Answer for use by future readers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

restTemplate.postForLocation("uri.com", new HttpEntity<>("{\"messages\": [ { \\"to\\": \""+Number+"\", \"content\": \"txt \" } ] }", headers));